Picture Number in String Vertex Operator
How can I know what is the Picture of a particular vertex operator? 
For example in 8.3.15 in Polchinski's book Vol.1, the Vertex Operators for the Enhanced Gauge symmetry are given by
\begin{equation}
\partial X^\mu e^{i k \cdot X} e^{\pm \frac{2i}{\sqrt{\alpha'}} X_R ^{25}}, \qquad  \bar{\partial} X^\mu e^{i k \cdot X} e^{\pm \frac{2i}{\sqrt{\alpha'}} X_L ^{25}}
\end{equation}
but how can I know what is the Picture of these Operators, i.e. if I need to modify them in order to compute correctly amplitudes?

What do you mean by "Picture" here?

Presumably related to picture-changing operators.

there is no picture number in bosonic string theory, so are you asking about how to distinguish fixed from integrated picture (which does exist in bosonic string theory), or are you asking about the notion of picture changing operators that only exists in one of the superstrings (when odd moduli exist in particular)
